# Sql function coding

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I show all odd numbers between min_value and max_value in sql?

Best regards

Comment: Generate them using recursive CTE or iterational stored procedure.

Comment: Function can neither return a list of values (but may return scalar value with serialized values list, for example, CSV string or JSON array) nor send something to the output.

Comment: You need to generate all numbers or already have a list of numbers between 2 values? if the latter use MOD to establish odd numbers

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Akina, using recursive CTE with @min_value and @max_value input variables.

```
;WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT @min_value
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < @max_value
)
SELECT n
FROM cte
WHERE (n MOD 2) <> 0;
```